# Handle Select box value with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have select box with multiple dynamic values. How do I handle the value of select box, Please suggest way to optimize Jquery.

**HTML:**

```
  <select name="alphabet">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
    <option value="E">E</option>
</select>
```

**Jquery:**

```
var alphabet = "B";

if (alphabet == "A") {
    $('select[name^="alphabet"] option[value="A"]').attr("selected", "selected");
} else if (alphabet == "B") {
    $('select[name^="alphabet"] option[value="B"]').attr("selected", "selected");
} else if (alphabet == "C") {
    $('select[name^="alphabet"] option[value="C"]').attr("selected", "selected");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ysaa4uyc/2/

Thanks.

Comment: `How do I handle the value of select box on , ` what?

Comment: How do I handle the value of select box, (my bad)

Comment: `$('select[name^="alphabet"] option[value="' + alphabet + '"]').attr("selected", "selected");`?

Comment: [`$('select[name^="alphabet"]').val(alphabet);`?](http://jsfiddle.net/ysaa4uyc/3/)

Comment: Thanks @PeeHaa. it works..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/ysaa4uyc/4/

```
$('select[name^="alphabet"] option[value='+alphabet+']').attr("selected", "selected");
```

Answer (score 0):

By you're example, if you want your jQuery to be more modular to allow for as many or as little values as you want then you can do it based on the variable.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var letters = 'ABCDE';
  var random = Math.round(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
  var letter = letters.substring(random - 1, random);
  $('select[name^="alphabet"] option[value="' + letter + '"]').attr("selected", "selected");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="alphabet">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
  <option value="D">D</option>
  <option value="E">E</option>
</select>
```

The main line is:

```
$('select[name^="alphabet"] option[value="' + letter + '"]').attr("selected", "selected");
```

This does a dynamic input based on your variable, or in my example based on the output of variable `letter`.

---

If you want to find out the current selected value, you can do a look up on the select `change()`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select[name^="alphabet"]').change(function() {
    var value = $(this).find(':selected').val();
    $('.output').text(value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="alphabet">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
  <option value="D">D</option>
  <option value="E">E</option>
</select>
<div>Value: <span class="output"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to the select box (having name attribute is not mandatory)

```
<select id="alphabet" name="alphabet">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
  <option value="D">D</option>
  <option value="E">E</option>
</select>
```

If you are expecting for multiple selection of values, use 'multiple' attribute in the select box

```
 <select id="alphabet" multiple>
   <option value="A">A</option>
   <option value="B">B</option>
   <option value="C">C</option>
   <option value="D">D</option>
   <option value="E">E</option>
 </select>
```

Using id of the select box, selected value can be taken as

```
  $('select[id=alphabet]').val();
```

You can test the selected value using any event on the select box like

```
 $('select[id=alphabet]').change(function() {
     alert($('select[id=alphabet]').val());
 });
```

Above code will work for both single/multiple selection of values.